# Need help setting up B2B Authentication in Azure AD

Tags: azure

I've set up Azure AD authentication on a existing web app and that works ok.

I then want to add "Users in partner companies" via CSV upload.  But the account I use to administer Azure is my company account so the option is not available.

[image]

So I then created a APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com account.

[image]

But when I log in to the portal with that, it's not linked to any subscriptions so obviously it can't add any users to the AD.

[image]

And I can't add the user to the subscription as they are not recognised.

[image]

I appreciate I'm probably missing/misunderstanding something fundamental but can anyone explain what I need to do to be able to enable B2B collaboration?

Comment: If you look at your list of subscriptions is APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com the default directory for any subscription? You currently can't do B2B invites unless it is the default directory for some Azure subscription and unless you pick APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com from the drop down in the top right of the portal. We have had to create a new empty Azure subscription with APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com as the default directory and make the B2B a subscription admin.

Comment: Ahh!  Fantastic.  I knew there would be something fundamental I was missing!

Comment: Ok - does anyone know why we can't change the default AD for the subscription?  Trying to follow the instructions here [link](http://blog.atwork.at/post/2015/08/07/How-to-change-the-default-directory-for-an-existing-Azure-subscription.aspx)  but there is no Edit Directory option visible??

Comment: posted my comment as an answer and added some text about changing the default directory. Let me know if that isn't the solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your list of subscriptions is APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com the default directory for any subscription? You currently can't do B2B invites unless it is the default directory for some Azure subscription and unless you pick APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com from the drop down in the top right of the portal. We have had to create a new empty Azure subscription with APPNAME.onmicrosoft.com as the default directory and make the B2B a subscription admin.

Now in order to [switch the default directory of the subscription](http://blog.atwork.at/post/2015/08/07/How-to-change-the-default-directory-for-an-existing-Azure-subscription.aspx) my recollection is that you have to be logged in with a Microsoft account (LiveID) rather than an organizational account.